# Windows selfhosted service - Setting custom service properties like description etc

Tags: servicestack

A windows service has several properties like servicename, servicedisplayname, description etc. Some of these props can be set with `sc.exe` but not all of them.

I have several ServiceStack services and want to give them other names than the exe file and add displayname, description etc.

I was looking at the `InstallUtil.exe` tool, but it seems not to offer this functionality.

How can I set these props with a ServiceStack service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Windows Service using the [ServiceStack VS.NET Templates](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS) it will generate a solution layout similar to:

[image]

The Windows Service properties name will appear in the properties tab after clicking on **serviceInstaller** in the `WinServiceInstaller.cs` Component designer view.

Comment: Cool, has everything even a service account! Great!